# Rotating IPs and user agents using Scrapy CrawlerRunner

Tags: scrapy, python-requests, web-crawler

I haven't set up my spider as a Scrapy project, so don't have the settings.py file for settings. But I still want to implement as many methods as I can to avoid being blocked/blacklisted. Is there any way to add these rotations and settings outside of a Scrapy project and only within the CrawlerRunner function???

Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#scrapy.crawler.CrawlerRunner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is wondering, there isn't a way to do this when using the CrawlerRunner function. I just had to set up a Scrapy project which didn't end up being as hard as I thought it would be. Theres plenty of info and "hello world" tutorials to follow online.

Good luck!